# (stm32f4) GPIOx_BSRR vs GPIOx_ODR

Tags: hardware, stm32

I am learning stm32f4.

Why do we have GPIO port output data register (GPIOx_ODR) when GPIO port bit set/reset register (GPIOx_BSRR) still exists?

Comment: freedom of choice.  if using many of the bits as a parallel port for example vs forcing bits one way or another.  I think some cortex-ms allow you to actually modify one bit in ODR for example using a feature in the core to do the read-modify-write for you.  I like when a design has both a write one to set or write one to reset register or registers, as well as a flat output register for all the bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main reason is to have atomic access to GPIOs.

In case of `ODR` register, if you want change only one bit then you need to use read - modify - write method which is non atomic, is slow and also unsafe if you want to control some GPIOS from different threads or also from interrupt handler, then can happen race condition.

Usage of `BSRR` register is atomic and this has some advantage, you can with single write set or clear certain output(s) without reading and modifying before write. It is faster and is thread safe.

Disadvantage of using `BSRR` is only f you want only toggle one bit without knowing actual state of certain bit. (to keep atomicity, you need remember actual value)